# Does every hosting company provide a redirect to their site at mysql.xyz.com?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

If `xyz` be the name of the website, does `mysql.xyz.com` always redirect to the webhost?

Answer (score 1):

No, depends on how they have setup the name servers with A Records.